# Where can i find my stylesheet in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sass, less

I am trying to change my stylesheet but i can't find it in Wordpress. I also use LESS/SASS. Searched over the whole internet but can't find my solution, so I try it via Stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What...the WHOLE internet...that must have taken a while!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login into WordPress, there you should have a section called "Themes" or "Design". Choose "Theme Editor". There will be a list of all the files you can edit, the CSS stylesheet should be named style.css.

Answer (score 0):

You should find it in the following directory `wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css`. If you're theme is using LESS and SASS then there may be a folder for those files.

Answer (score 0):

Often in :

```
wp-content/themes/theme_name/style.css
```

But often, there are many stylesheets. You can view source of you website to get the name of avtices stylesheets (if you see `<link>` with XXX.css, you know that this style sheet is active, and you can get the path).